# Can a website be created without "position:" tags?

Tags: html, css, position

So far I have created two websites and I can't finish them because of position tags. I have two sidebars and they make the problem. My question is, can a website be created without position: tags?

Update: This tutorial helped me a lot. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jV8B24rSN5o

Comment: Look into [CSS grid layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: I really don't understand this. Is there any online layout generator?

Comment: Please share the code you have come up with and the illustration of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, shure. As say @Sawny, you can make it by integration you page tags with Grid layout. Like in this instruction -> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Also you can make it in more easly way by using a flex layout -> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

And the most common way to leave `position:` option outdoor css - use `float:` style option instead.

P.S.
This tips above must help you a lot. If not, then you need to learn more about css.

Comment: I created this just to ask you something. Why does the header goes under two sidebars? How to make it go between two sidebars?

`<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="sidebar1">
</div>
<div id="sidebar2">
 </div>
<div id="header">
 </div>
</body>
</html>`
`body {
 margin: 0;}
#sidebar1 {
 float: left;
 width: 70px;
 height: 1800px;
 background-color: red;}
#sidebar2 {
 float: right;
 width: 70px;
 height: 1800px;
 background-color: yellow;}
#header {
 width: auto;
 height: 120px;
 background-color: black;}`

Comment: Try next: 

`<html> 
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> </head> <body> 
  <div id="sidebar1"> </div> 
  <div id="header"> 11231 </div> 
  <div id="sidebar2"> </div>  
</body> 
</html> `

`body { margin: 0;} 
#sidebar1 { float: left; width: 70px; height: 1800px; background-color: red;} 
#sidebar2 { float: right; width: 70px; height: 1800px; background-color: yellow;} 
#header { display:inline-block; width: calc(100% - 140px); margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 120px; background-color: black;}`